# Use Powermail in Typo3 6.2.4

Tags: forms, email, typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I'm using typo3 6.2.4 and powermail 2.0.16

I need to create a form who send a mail to me.

I created the form with the page and the fields. One is the name and one is the mail to test.

After, I created the content element with the plugin powermail and now, I need to display the form in the frontend. I have active the static "Main Template" and "Add basic CSS". I try this code but it's not working.

```
  page = PAGE
  page.10 = CONTENT
  page.10.table = tt_content
  page.10.select {

    where = colPos = 0
    orderBy = sorting
  }

  page.10.renderObj = COA
  page.10.renderObj {

    10 = TEXT
    10.field = header
    10.wrap = <div class="header">|</div>

    20 = TEXT
    20.field = bodytext
    20.wrap = <div class="bodytext">|</div>
  }
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Create a content element with the plugin powermail ?

Comment: I change my sentence, I think I'm not clear. It is created.

Comment: Lets continue this discussion in a chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59796/room-for-xatenev-and-string-myname-awashi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is here : [Nothing appears in Typo3 with powermail (Frontend)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25551151/nothing-appears-in-typo3-with-powermail-frontend)

It seems that you are missing the proper typoscript to actually show the form on the page. The specified typoscript snippet is not enough to show the content elements on the page.

Inside your typoscript template include the css_styled_content static template and change the snippet to this:

```
# Default PAGE object:
page = PAGE

page.10 < styles.content.get
```

That should ensure proper showing on the frontend. This is basic as it is, if you want it to be better looking, or different templating you should take a look at templating with TYPO3 first.

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking with you here, did you add this as a template in the typoscript template configuration? Like

Comment: I don't understand, you talk about the static Template "Main template (powermail)" and "Add basic CSS (powermail)"? If it's that, yes, I did.

Comment: So, it's not that because it's doing