# Nothing appears in Typo3 with powermail (Frontend)

Tags: forms, email, typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I need help with powermail. 
I'm using Typo3 6.2.4 and powermail 2.0.16.
Something is wrong cause nothing appear in the frontend, but I don't what and I need some helps.

I created a new root page with the basic template "HELLO WORLD!" (ID = 15).

```
# Default PAGE object:
page = PAGE

page.10 = TEXT
page.10.value = HELLO WORLD!
```

In this template, I included two statics templates : "Main Template (powermail)" and "Add basic CSS (powermail)"

After that, in the root page, I created the folder "Powermail" to stock the data. (ID = 241)

And I created a second folder ("Form"; ID = 242).

In the folder "Form", I created a new Form ("registration") with the setting : Layout=Layout1; Language=Default; And the checkbox "Hide" is not checked

In this one, one Pages ("registration data") with the setting : Layout=Layout2; Language=Default; And the checkbox "Hide" is not checked

In "registration data", two fields, one for the name (Name of the sender) and one for the mail (Email of the sender) with setting : Mandatory Field=Checked; Layout=Layout3; Language=Default; And the checkbox "Hide" is not checked

And after that, in the root page, I created a new content element "powermail".

In the tab General, I set the header = Registration

In the tab Plugin, I selected Powermail. After, this is the setting : Selected Items=registration; Confirm page=checked;

Receivers Name=My Name; Receivers Email=MyName@gmail.com; Subject=My test;

Sender Name=A Name; Sender Email=AName@gmail.com; Subject=test;

In the tab Behaviour, Recursive=0 levels;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are missing the proper typoscript to actually show the form on the page.
The specified typoscript snippet is not enough to show the content elements on the page.

Inside your typoscript template include the css_styled_content static template and change the snippet to this:

```
# Default PAGE object:
page = PAGE

page.10 < styles.content.get
```

That should ensure proper showing on the frontend. This is basic as it is, if you want it to be better looking, or different templating you should take a look at templating with TYPO3 first.

Comment: I have one more question, is it possible to remplace styles.content.get by my own typoscript? How I do that?

Comment: A little late, but still an answer to the question. You can always provide your own typoscript (TS). In fact, the styles.content.get is one giant preset typoscript 'array'. You can complete override it or simply replace little things.

You might benefit from the information on the Typoscript in 45 minutes tutorial, [link](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptIn45MinutesTutorial/)